# How to get a check box in a table using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need to fix this code I dont understand what is wrong with the checkbox.

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // this is the if statement
        echo "<table border='1'><tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Usernames</th>
            <th>Password</tr>"; //table headings
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row["ID"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["Username"]."</td>
            <td>".$row<input type='checkbox'/>."</td> //this part needs to be fixed
             </tr>"; // the problem is in this table
            }
            echo "</table>";// the code runs using a database and all information on the sql is correct
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
```

Comment: You're outputting passwords to the page?

Comment: Its supposed to be a sortof admin page

Comment: @JayBlanchard so yes

Comment: That really is just a bad plan. No one, and I mean ***no one***, should have access to user's passwords. Not even admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but something like this should work for that line.

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name='something' value='".$row['ID']."' /></td>
```

In your original code, the HTML for the checkbox was not part of the string, but instead looked like it was trying to be part of the `$row` variable, which was a syntax error.

Comment: [You're welcome.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) By the way, this checkbox thing seems probably pretty harmless, but you should definitely heed Jay Blanchard's warning regarding access to passwords.